# Open the correct image on a carousel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

I have several image thumbnails in my component that when clicked open a modal with Swiper.js displaying a carousel with the larger images and it's working ok. but I needed to find a way to open directly to the image that the user clicks on, because right no matter which one the user clicks on, it's always opening the first, from the beginning.

```
    "use client";
    import Navbar from "@/app/components/navbar";
    import Image from "next/image";
    import { projects } from "../../data/projects";
    import { useState } from "react";
    import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
    import { Navigation, Pagination } from "swiper/modules";
    
    import "swiper/css";
    import "swiper/css/navigation";
    import "swiper/css/pagination";
    import "swiper/css/thumbs";
    
    const ProjetoDetalhes = ({ params }: any) => {
      const proj = projects.find((proj) => proj.id.toString() === params.id);
    
      const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false);
      const [selectedImageIndex, setSelectedImageIndex] = useState<number | null>(
        null
      );
    
      const openModal = (index: number) => {
        setSelectedImageIndex(index);
        setModalIsOpen(true);
      };
    
      const closeModal = () => {
        setSelectedImageIndex(null);
        setModalIsOpen(false);
      };
    
      return (
      <>
      ...

      <div className="flex flex-wrap gap-4 mt-12 w-full justify-center sm:justify-start">
            {proj?.fotos.map((foto, index) => (
              <div
                key={index}
                onClick={() => openModal(index)}
                className="grid grid-cols-2 h-44 w-44 relative"
              >
                <Image
                  src={foto}
                  alt={`Imagem ${index + 1}`}
                  fill
                  className="cursor-pointer object-cover"
                />
              </div>
            ))}

            {/* modal, swiper */}
            {modalIsOpen && selectedImageIndex !== null && (
              <div
                className="fixed inset-0 flex items-center justify-center min-h-screen"
                onClick={closeModal}
              >
                <div className="absolute inset-0 bg-black opacity-75"></div>
                <div className="relative" onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
                  <button
                    onClick={closeModal}
                    className="absolute top-4 right-4 text-white text-3xl z-50"
                  >
                    &times;
                  </button>

                  <div className="overflow-hidden">
                    <div className="container">
                      <Swiper
                        navigation
                        pagination={{ type: "fraction" }}
                        modules={[Navigation, Pagination]}
                        className="md:h-[50em] md:w-[80em] h-96 w-96"
                      >
                        {proj?.fotos.map((foto, index) => (
                          <SwiperSlide key={index}>
                            <div className="flex h-full w-full items-center justify-center">
                              <Image
                                src={foto}
                                alt={`Imagem ${index + 1}`}
                                className="block object-contain h-full w-full"
                                fill
                              />
                            </div>
                          </SwiperSlide>
                        ))}
                      </Swiper>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
};

export default ProjetoDetalhes;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open the Swiper modal directly to the image that the user clicks on, you can set the initial slide index of the Swiper component to the index of the clicked image.

> Pass the selectedImageIndex state to the Swiper component.
> Set the initialSlide prop of the Swiper component to selectedImageIndex.

```html
<Swiper
  navigation
  pagination={{ type: "fraction" }}
  modules={[Navigation, Pagination]}
  className="md:h-[50em] md:w-[80em] h-96 w-96"
  initialSlide={selectedImageIndex !== null ? selectedImageIndex : 0} // Set initial slide index
>
  {proj?.fotos.map((foto, index) => (
    <SwiperSlide key={index}>
      <div className="flex h-full w-full items-center justify-center">
        <Image
          src={foto}
          alt={`Imagem ${index + 1}`}
          className="block object-contain h-full w-full"
          fill
        />
      </div>
    </SwiperSlide>
  ))}
</Swiper>
```